# Предел выполнения рекурсии

Tags: python, c++, рекурсия

Добрый всем день или доброе утро а может и ночь! Мне нужно решить такую задачу (рекурсия обязательна)
есть схема состоящая из кусков по 3 резистора. Ее длина задаться в задаче как число которое вводит пользователь. Каждый резистор имеет сопротивление 1 Ом (пускай будет R для центрального резистора в каждом куске) значит ли это что сопротивление 1 куска равно 1+1+1=3 но это для последовательного соединения дальше идёт параллельное а значит сопротивление будет равно ((1+1+1)*1)/((1+1+1)+1) а для самой задачи это будет формулой R=(R+2)/(R+3) у меня задача реализована на питоне и с++ но проблема остаться такой же, при вводе большого числа типа 32000 в с++ и 3000 в питоне код выдает ничего, просто пустой экран с ретурн и большое число. Также если можно то поправьте мой код на обеих языках. Спасибо!
[image]
Питон

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
def Rx(r):
global ans
if(r>1):
    Rx(r-1)
ans=(ans+2)/(ans+3)
return ans

a=int(input())
ans=1.0
if(a!=1):
    print (Rx(a)+2)
else:
print(3)
```

С++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
float ans=1;
float Rx(long long r)
{
    if(r>1){
        Rx(r-1);
    }
    return ans=(ans+2)/(ans+3);
}

int main()
{
    long long a;
    cin >> a;
    if(a!=1){
    cout << fixed << setprecision(15)<<Rx(a)+2;
    }
    else{ 
        cout << 3;
    }
}
```

[image: питон проблема]
[image: с++ проблема]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обе версии написаны неправильно. Например, вызов Rx никуда не записывается, так какой смысл возвращать (глобальный) ans?

Вот так фурычит:

```
def recres(numc):
    if numc <= 1:
        return 3
    res = recres(numc - 1)
    return 2 + res/(1+res)
```

Формула тут такая - имея сопротивление `res`, мы добавляем параллельное ему 1, получается `res * 1 / (res + 1)`, и добавляем 2 для двух последовательных резисторов.

Или так (переформируем дробь, чтобы одно использование было)

```
def recres(numc):
    if numc <= 1:
        return 3
    return 3 - 1 / (1 + recres(numc - 1))
```

---

Рекурсия по сути не нужна, достаточно цикла

```
def resist(numc):
    if numc <= 0:
        return None
    res = 3
    for i in range(numc - 1):
        res = 2 + res/(1+res)
    return res
```

Однако для длинных цепочек считать особо и не нужно, т.к. сходимость ряда очень быстрая, точности дабла не хватит, чтобы заметить различия после длины цепи 15. Получается, 32000 шагов - впустую.

Но есть у нас методы против Кости Сапрыкина, в советской школе давали.

При соединении бесконечно длинной цепочки с ещё одним звеном сопротивление не меняется, значит, можем записать

```
r*1/(r+1) + 2 = r
r^2  - 2r - 2 = 0
```

Решив квадратное уравнение, получим точный ответ

```
r = 1 + sqrt(3)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Я пока ещё в 8 классе и только начал изучать программирование, простите за мой плохой код.

Comment: Главное, чтобы разобрались.